# nav_menu: how to force a subpage switching on the parent menu

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I've been using the native wp_nav_menu to output my navigational elements. I have also created a subpage that is nested under one of my menu, but when I hit that URL the default custom walker clearly doesn't activate the corresponding item in the menu.

E.g.

```
Home, FAQs
      >____Archive
```

MY question is how can I get the FAQs menu turning on if I'm on the archive URL?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Does `FAQs` not have the class in the list-item `current-page-ancestor` to style?

Comment: Where's the code for the default custom walker?

Comment: @BradDalton I have used the custom walker, hence anything customised from my side.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee to clean up a bit the mess the wp_nav_menu creates by adding dozens of classes, I removed some of them. I can possibly look on how to get the current-page-ancestor replaced in a similar fashion to activate it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee sorry to go back to this, but I looking at the current-page-ancestor class, I can't find any. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: If you've removed classes using a custom walker maybe it's time to revert your changes and start over. By Default wp_nav_menu has a `current-page-ancestor` class, `current-page` class, `current-page-parent` class, and a ton other useful classes.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee that's what I did ... to be sure that I wasn't missing anything. And on an archive page (CPT) the class is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out from @Howdy_McGee it should be possible to use the current-menu-anchestor css class.

However, using the standard menu walker in a CPT archive page taxonomically nested under a menu item I wasn't able to get the class out as expected.

The solution I adopted was to add a create a filter to inject the required class

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'am_filter_menu_class' );
```